# How do I find what's inbetween " " in an inputted string?

Tags: java, string, iteration

I'd like to retrieve whatever is in quotes that someone enters as a string. I'm assuming I need to set a boolean value in the if statement and do something with that but I'm not sure how.

When the user inputs a string mixed with words and numbers all separated by one space:

```
 hey 110 say "I am not very good at Java" but " I can fish pretty well"
```

I want to determine what's a word, what's a digit and what's inside a quote.
I'm having trouble with the quote part

I want to be able to take the `"I am not very good at Java"` and the `"I can fish pretty well"` and print out what's inside the quotes, but there can be multiple quotes in the string.

I can't use

- split,
- trim,
- tokenizer,
- regex,
- or anything that would make this really easy unfortunately also I can't scan this twice so using loops inside my if is not ideal.

Below is what I have now. It's all in this method where I try to identify if something in the string is a word, number or a quote:

```
class Bean {
    int num;
    String word;
    String quote;
    String userInput;

    public Bean(String userInput)//
    {
        num=0;// initializing used variables and fields
        this.userInput=userInput;
    }

    public void set(String userInput)// method set returns void
    {
        num=0;// reset each variable so new input can be passed

        String empty="";
        String wordBuilder="";
        userInput+=" ";
        String quoteBuilder="";
        boolean quote=false;

        for(int index=0; index<userInput.length(); index++)// goes through each character in string
        {

            if(Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(index)))// checks if character in the string is a digit
            { 
                empty+=userInput.charAt(index);
            }
            else {
                if (Character.isLetter(userInput.charAt(index))) {
                    wordBuilder += userInput.charAt(index);
                } else {
                    if (userInput.charAt(index) == '"') {
                        quote = true;
                    }

                    if (quote = true) {
                        quoteBuilder += userInput.charAt(index);
                    }
                }
            }
            //if it is then parse that character into an integer and assign it to num
            num = Integer.parseInt(empty);
            word = wordBuilder;

            empty = "";
            wordBuilder = "";
        }
    } 
}
```